# Set heights to max in a complex CSS layout. In a wiki

Tags: layout, html, css

I'm building a layout and need to ensure some div heights expand to fill gaps as content in the divs grows. It has to be doable with inline style="..." CSS on divs, as this is embedded in a wiki page and i can't add stylesheets, javascript, etc.

In the following layout, LEFT-TOP-LEFT and LEFT-TOP-RIGHT need to span equally to the top of LEFT-BOTTOM. Sidebar 1 and Sidebar 2 need to both span down to Footer.

[image]

The basic HTML structure i'm using is as follows. The widths are simplified; in actuality the two sidebars are more like 15% and 15%. If it'd be easier with a different structure, i'm open to that too.

```
<div style="font-size:10px;width:40em;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#eee;color:#333;line-height:1.2em;">
  <div style="background-color:#ddd;border:1px solid #aaa;">header</div>

  <div style="float:left;width:20em;">
    <div style="float:left;width:20em;">
      <div style="float:left;width:10em;background-color:#aff;">
        <p>LEFT-TOP-LEFT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed
        auctor faucibus diam vitae rutrum. Cras feugiat, orci in pulvinar mattis, sem
        eros laoreet ligula, auctor sollicitudin nibh massa vitae ipsum. In non interdum ante.</p>
        </div>
      <div style="float:left;width:10em;background-color:#ccf;">
        <p>LEFT-TOP-RIGHT Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
        nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;width:20em;background-color:#aaf;"><p>LEFT-BOTTOM Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="float:right;width:20em;">
    <div style="float:right;width:20em;">
      <div style="float:left;width:10em;background-color:#77a;">
        '''Sidebar 1'''<p>RIGHT-1</p></div>
      <div style="float:left;width:10em;background-color:#a77;">
        '''Sidebar 2'''<p>RIGHT-2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Sed auctor faucibus diam vitae rutrum. </p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;color:#333;background-color:#ddd;"> Footer </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's way easier to fix this using JavaScript.

Comment: just create a background image with the different colors, and set this background image to a wrapper div, and set it to repeat-y

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `style="min-height:200px;"`

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely use display: table/table-row/table-cell:

http://jsfiddle.net/GW848/

Edit: noticed that the bottom element should only span to columns. Unfortunately rowspan and colspan are not available in CSS so you'll need to solve it some other way then.